# Multi-purpose bootable CD

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you recommend good (and not just any) free downloadable recovery CD](https://superuser.com/questions/47171/can-you-recommend-good-and-not-just-any-free-downloadable-recovery-cd)

Hey!

I was wondering what was the best bootable CD package out there. What I want is something that is lightweight, has diagnostic tools and with which you can perform basic operations on your system (fdisk, clear mbr etc).

The question came to my mind when I realized that I wanted to remove GRUB from my system without the Windows XP installation CD (aka. without the recovery console). I started searching the net for alternatives to it and I found some, but I really don't want to end up with an unusable system until I get home to my WinXP CD :).

Comment: I think this question is covered by  http://superuser.com/questions/47171/can-you-recommend-good-and-not-just-any-free-downloadable-recovery-cd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

[Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) comes with lots

[BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) you can build yourself with the packages you want

[Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) contains some shareware and commercial products which you will need to register or own to be able to use legally

Answer (score 0):

I like [PartMagic](http://partedmagic.com/)

Answer (score 0):

#### [Ultimate Boot CD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) aka UBCD4Win

A bootable recovery CD that contains software used for repairing, restoring, or diagnosing almost any computer problem. Sort of Windows version of the Ultimate Boot CD.

It's based on Bart's PE (a Windows "pre-install" environment CD, basically a simple Windows® XP booted from CD) and have a multi-boot system to launch other boot disks and many useful plug-ins built-in.

It includes network support and allows you the ability to modify NTFS volumes, recover deleted files, create new NTFS volumes, scan hard drives for viruses, etc.

[List of tools](http://www.ubcd4win.com/contents.htm) (outdated)

[image]

[image]