# What's a good setup CD

Tags: software-rec, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Multi-purpose bootable CD](https://superuser.com/questions/117155/multi-purpose-bootable-cd)
>   [Can you recommend good (and not just any) free downloadable recovery CD](https://superuser.com/questions/47171/can-you-recommend-good-and-not-just-any-free-downloadable-recovery-cd)

What's a good bootable setup CD with a bunch of tools like partitioner, wiper, linux, etc on it?

Thanks!

Comment: also dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/47171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hiren's Boot CD.](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) Live Windows, and stuffed full of utilties. For Live Linux, well, just have a Ubuntu Disk.